# Asp.net mvc dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having a bugger of a time trying to figure out where I am going wrong.  Scenario is this.  Trying to add an object that has a foreign key in it with mvc entity framework.

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int TestItem { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select an Employee Type")]
    public virtual EmployeeType EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }
}


 public class EmployeeType
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string EmployeeTypeName { get; set; }


}
```

Those are the two pocos for the entities.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PersonViewModel pv = new PersonViewModel();
        ViewBag.EmployeeTypeSelect= new SelectList(db.EmployeeTypes, "EmployeeTypeId", "EmployeeTypeName");
        return View(pv);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Person/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PersonViewModel personVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.EmployeeTypeId = personVM.EmployeeTypeId;
            person.FirstName = personVM.FirstName;
            person.LastName = personVM.LastName;
            person.TestItem = personVM.TestItem;
            db.Persons.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(personVM);
    }
```

That is the controller.

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.PersonViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>PersonViewModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestItem)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestItem)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestItem)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeTypeId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.EmployeeTypeId,(SelectList)ViewBag.EmployeeTypeSelect)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeTypeId)
    </div>




    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

That is the view.

Everything works fine with the view off the initial get, but when I post the EmployeeTypeId has a null value.  I check the source and the select list is fine, has proper values and text.  Please help as I have no clue where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML for the View? Eventually, using Fiddler or any debug tool for the browser, you can check the POST data from the Page, just to see what values are being sent up to the server and why (if) the server is not mapping them correctly.

Comment: Using fiddler i can see that browser is posting data, its the app that isn't mapping it to the variable

Comment: When you say it is posting data, you mean it is returning something like: "EmployeeTypeId = 2"? What kind is the property in the PersonViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in Html.EndForm() in the HTML after all of the values you wish to post and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: RE: (Adding empty constructors to the viewmodels) I've read that elsewhere, too. Not sure if this depends on the situation, but mine seem to work fine as long as there is a constructor. Not sure why. I had put a bunch of empty constructors in my app only to realize that everything still worked fine without them.

Answer (score 0):

Your Person and EmployeeType class needs to have a default (empty) constructor for the model binding to work -

```
 public class EmployeeType
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string EmployeeTypeName { get; set; }

    public EmployeeType()
    {
    }
}

public class Person {
    [Key]
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int TestItem { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select an Employee Type")]
    public virtual EmployeeType EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
       EmployeeTypeId = new EmployeeType();
    }
}
```

Also, try in your view, making it

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.EmployeeTypeId.EmployeeTypeId,(SelectList)ViewBag.EmployeeTypeSelect)`